I need to use RestTemplate for requesting a token to the server and my code contains everything is required, but response body is null
I need to use RestTemplate to request a token to the server and my code contains everything is required, but the response body is null, I have tried exchange and postforentity and the response is the same.
The request was posted by Postman and the response is correct with token in responseBody.
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_URL = "http://localhost:8084/api/auth/login";
        
    private Disposable token;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/TempResp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String gethttpResp(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String username = loginDto.getUsername();
        String password = loginDto.getPassword();
        String response = null;
        try {
                // create user authentication object
                User authenticationUser = getAuthenticationUser(loginDto);
                // convert the user authentication object to JSON
                String authenticationBody = getBody(authenticationUser);
                // create headers specifying that it is JSON request
                HttpHeaders authenticationHeaders = getHeaders();
                HttpEntity<String> authenticationEntity = new HttpEntity<String> 
                        (authenticationBody,authenticationHeaders);
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
//              HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//              headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
//              headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

                // Authenticate User and get JWT
                ResponseEntity<ResponseToken> authenticationResponse = 
                        restTemplate.postForEntity(AUTHENTICATION_URL,
                        authenticationEntity, ResponseToken.class);
                    
                // if the authentication is successful      
                System.out.println(authenticationResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK));
                // if the authentication is successful      
                if (authenticationResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                    String token = "Bearer " + authenticationResponse.getBody().getToken();
                    System.out.println("Token is " + token)

                }
                
                            
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
            
    
        }
        return response;
        
    }


HttpEntity<String> authenticationEntity = new HttpEntity<String> 
                        (authenticationBody,authenticationHeaders);

was changed to
HttpEntity<Object> authenticationEntity = new HttpEntity<> 
                        (authenticationBody,authenticationHeaders);

and the results were correct for the token in response.body.
